# ID value in AWS DynamoDB for having unique values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my single table DynamoDB design. I had UUID has Id although when I want to create unique values it is an hassle and expensive since I will have to scan the db for the name since the way DynamoDB condition expression works is it will retrieve one value of the PK and SK and compares it. So I followed other technique mentioned in this article https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-condition-expressions/
which works great.

Therefore UUID is not getting used rather just the name of entity as the ID with empty spaces filled with _ . Eg: Company#Dell, Company#The_Facebook. So when I want to retreive an item of ID, I almost use the name. Is there a security issue to use just name as Id or is this anti pattern.

The other way I can do is add a simple hash function to create Id which is reproducable based on the name and therefore we can maintain uniqueness based on the the PK and SK using condition expression.

```
function hashCode(s) {
    for(var i = 0, h = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        h = Math.imul(31, h) + s.charCodeAt(i) | 0;
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is: "is it secure to store `name` as the partition key in DynamoDB"?

Data stored in DynamoDB is secured by default, all tables have server side encryption enabled. You can further take control of the encryption type by using your own KMS keys.

Using `name` instead of a UUID is not an anti-pattern as long as the cardinality of it is not low, which would impact your throughput performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand AWS DDB is secure. My question since I am using a guessable item id, is it possible now to have brute force by guessing the name. The very reason why uuid is used as id for entities